lower bound of $\ell_2$ norm of sequence
Let $x=(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an infinite sequence such that $x_i$'s are non-zero and $\lvert x\rvert_1=\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_i\rvert=r>0$ (the sum converges). Then due to our assumption, we know $0<\lvert x \rvert_2<\infty$. where $\lvert x \rvert_2=\left(\sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \lvert x_i\rvert^2\right)^{1/2}$.
My question: can we provide a non-zero lower bound of $\lvert x \rvert_2$ such that this lower bound is an expression of $\lvert x \rvert_1$? In other words, can we quantify how small $\lvert x \rvert_2$ is via the knowledge that $\lvert x \rvert_1=r$?

Consider sequences where the first $n$ elements are close to $r/n$, and the remaining elements are close to zero.

Thank you for the comment! If one consider the type of sequences you describe, getting lower bound of $\ell_2$ norm is indeed straightforward. However in my opinion, such type of infinite sequences are too close to being a finite sequence of just $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and the answer to my question is trivial for finite sequences.

For $x=(r/n, \dots, r/n, 0, 0, 0, \ldots)$ you have $\Vert x \Vert_2 = r/\sqrt n$, which means that there is no positive lower bound. If you require that all $x_i$ are non-zero then the same is true, just technically a bit more complicated.

Thank you! I see.

Fix $n\in\mathbb N$, $\def\d{\delta}\d>0$ with $\d<r/n$. Let
$$
x=\Big(\overbrace{\frac rn,\ldots,\frac rn}^{n-1\ \text {times}},\frac rn-\d,\frac\d2,\frac\d4,\frac\d8,\ldots\Big).
$$
Then $|x|_1=r$, while
$$
|x|_2=\Big(\frac{(n-1)r^2}{n^2}+\big(\frac rn -\d\big)^2+\d^2\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac1{4^j}\Big)^{1/2}
=\Big(\frac{r^2}{n}-\frac{2\d}n+\frac{\d^2}3\Big)^{1/2}.
$$
If you take $\d=\frac r{2n}$, then
$$
|x|_2=\Big(\frac{r^2}n-\frac r{n^2}+\frac{r^2}{12n^2}\Big)^{1/2}\leq\Big(\frac{13r^2}{12n}\Big)^{1/2}.
$$
As $n$ can be chosen arbitrarily large, the norm $|x|_2$ can be made as close to zero as desired.

Over the space $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, we have
$$\|a\|_2^2=\sum_{i}|a_i|^2\le (\sum_i |a_i|)^2=\|a\|_1^2$$
$$\|a\|_2\le \|a\|_1$$
If there is a function $f:(0, \infty)\rightarrow(0, \infty)$, such that $\|a\|_2\ge f(\|a\|_1)$ for all $a\in\ell^1(\mathbb N)\setminus\{0\}$, in particular we have $\|\frac{a}{\|a\|_1}\|_2\ge f(1), \|a\|_2\ge f(1)\|a\|_1$. Combined, we have $$f(1)\|a\|_1\le\|a\|_2\le \|a\|_1$$ that is the $1$-norm and $2$-norm are equivalent on $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, therefore since $\|\cdot\|_1$ is complete, $\|\cdot\|_2$ is also complete. This proves that any sequence in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ must be also in $\ell^1(\mathbb N)$, but this is definitely not the case, as e.g. $(\frac{1}{i})_{i\in\mathbb N} \in\mathbb N\in \ell^2(\mathbb N)\setminus\ell^1(\mathbb N)$.
From this, we can also cook an easy concrete example: let $a_n = (1, 1/2, \cdots, 1/n, 0, 0, \cdots), b_n = \frac{1}{\|a_n\|_1}a_n$, then we have $\|b_n\|_1=1$ but $\|b_n\|_2=\frac{1}{\|a_n\|_1}\|a_n\|_2\rightarrow 0$, as $\|a_n\|_1\rightarrow \infty$ and $\|a_n\|_2\rightarrow \frac{\pi^2}{6}<\infty$.

+1 In the last line: don´t You mean $(\frac{1}{i})_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\in\ell^2(\mathbb{N})\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$?

@PeterMelech Thank you! Fixed.

For a real number $a \in (0, 1)$ consider the sequence
$$
 x = (r(1-a), r(1-a)a, r(1-a)a^2, r(1-a)a^3, \ldots) \, .
$$
Then (using the geometric series formula):
$$
 \Vert x \Vert_1 = r(1-a)\frac{1}{1-a} = r
$$
and
$$
\Vert x \Vert_2 = r(1-a)\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} = r \sqrt{\frac{1-a}{1+a}} \, .
$$
This shows that $\Vert x \Vert_2$ can be arbitrarily close to zero for sequences with $\Vert x \Vert_1 = r$, i.e. there is no such positive lower bound.
